# Apply returned value from function in all Dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to assign a value from a function in all rows of a Dataframe in a new column.
i.e. the df below should contain  new column called `random number` with the random number generated in the `get_random()` function.

```
import pandas as pd
from random import random

def get_random():
    return random()

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I tried the below, but I get the error `get_random takes 0 positional arguments`

```
df['random number'] = df.apply(get_random)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either do

```
df['random number'] = df.apply(lambda x: random())
```

or change get_random to

```
def get_random(x):
    return random()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the function `random`:

```
def get_random(x):
    return random()
```

as apply expects the function to take an input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list-comprehension

```py
df['random number'] = [get_random() for i in range(len(df))]
```